# Disable flight mode in android 2.2

Tags: android, offline-mode

I am working with an android app that allows enabling of flight mode. The enabling part is working fine. Now the problem arises when the user exists/quits the application. I want the flight mode to be disabled once the user quits the app. Is there a possibility of doing it programmatically or should the user turn of the setting manually?

```
 if ((flightMode.isChecked()))
    {

          boolean isEnabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
          Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
          flag=1;
          Toast.makeText(this, "flight mode on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(isEnabled == false)
            {

            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,1);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", 1);
            sendBroadcast(intent);


            }

            }
      else
        {
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
            intent.putExtra("state", 0);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
             Toast.makeText(this, "flight mode off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

And to disable I use this code :

```
                       alt_bld .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                       alt_bld .setCancelable(true);
               alt_bld.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
                {

                if(flag==1)
                {
                   Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                   Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0);
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
                                        intent.putExtra("state", 0);
                                        sendBroadcast(intent);


                            }
                            finish();

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  Make sure your manifest contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

and the system settings should stay the way your app sets them.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the exact same thing in one of my apps.

You're asking what should the policy be?  Here's what I did:  When my app starts up, it makes a note of the current airplane mode and stores a flag accordingly.  If the device is already in airplane mode, it does nothing.  Otherwise, it enters airplane mode.

When the app exits, it checks the flag it stored to see if the device was in airplane mode at startup, in which case it does nothing. If the flag indicates that the device had not been in airplane mode, it now turns airplane mode back off.

The heuristic is not perfect -- if the system kills my app, and I restart it later, the restarted instance will observe that the device is in airplane mode, but will not remember that it had previously not been in airplane mode.

The code looks approximately like this:

```
class MyClass extends Activity {
    ...
    boolean airplaneMode;               // currently-desired airplane mode
    boolean oldAirplaneMode;            // airplane mode at startup
    ...
    onCreate(Bundle savedState) {

        if (savedState != null) {
            oldAirplaneMode = savedState.getBoolean("oldAirplaneMode");
            airplaneMode = state.getBoolean("airplaneMode");
        }

        // Programming notes:  On initial
        // startup we note the initial airplane mode and take no other
        // action.  On subsequent entries to this method, we confirm that
        // the current airplane mode is what we want, and set it if needed.
        //
        // If airplane mode was initially enabled when the app started,
        // then we leave it that way.
        //
        // If for some reason, the program exits before the plane lands, then         
        // airplane mode will remain on.  It is the user's responsibility to
        // restore phone mode in that case.

        boolean mode = getAirplaneMode();
        // First startup; remember initial value of airplane mode
        if( savedState == null )
            oldAirplaneMode = airplaneMode = mode;
        else if( !oldAirplaneMode && mode != airplaneMode )
            setAirplaneMode(airplaneMode);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        state.putBoolean("autoAirplaneMode", autoAirplaneMode);
        state.putBoolean("oldAirplaneMode", oldAirplaneMode);
        state.putBoolean("airplaneMode", airplaneMode);
    }

    private void eventYadaYada() {
        // Should we be in airplane mode now?
        boolean mode = decideIfWeShouldBeInAirplaneMode();
        if (!oldAirplaneMode) // Only act if we weren't in airplane mode at startup
        {
            if( airplaneMode != mode )
                setAirplaneMode(airplaneMode = mode);
        }
    }
}
```

Some details left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The app is literally for use in an airplane. When the GPS indicates the device is going fast enough to be flying, it goes into airplane mode. When the gps indicates the device has stopped again, it leaves airplane mode. That's all implementation detail however.